# Compose method in recompose Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, reduce, higher-order-functions

I was looking at the `compose` function in recompose library by @acdlite to compose boundary conditions for Higher Order Components and this is what it looks the compose function looks like

`const compose = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), arg => arg);`

However, I tried [Eric-Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043390/eric-elliott)'s one liner approach to compose, from https://medium.com/javascript-scene/reduce-composing-software-fe22f0c39a1d, specifically, this piece of code.

`const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), x);`

I tried using both these variants, in my react component like so,

```
const ListWithConditionalRendering = compose(
  withLoadingIndicator,
  withDataNull,
  withListEmpty
)(Users);
```

and they both seem to work fine. I am unable to understand if there is any difference in the way the above functions work, if so, what are they.

Comment: One uses Array's `reduce` function, the other, `reduceRight`...

Comment: The first one returns a pre-composed function, and the second one returns a scoped function that applies the composition when you call it.

Comment: @EmileBergeron : My bad, I probably wasn't clear enough. Yes, one uses reduce and the other uses reduceRight, but they both give the same results at the end. I understood the one which uses reduceRight, but couldn't really understand the one with reduce, as in how does the flow work. Can you please explain.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: That makes sense, thanks. Are there any negative scenarios or edge cases that you can think of where one would be better than the other. Also, if you could elaborate a bit on pre-compose and scoped function that applies the composition as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few differences for very niche scenarios that might be helpful to be aware of.

The first one precomposes a function, which means it calls `reduce()` when it is composed rather than when it will be called. In contrast, the second approach returns a scoped function that calls `reduceRight()` when it is *called*, rather than when it was composed.

The first method accepts multiple arguments to the last function in the array, while the second method only accepts one argument:

```js
const compose1 = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), arg => arg);
const compose2 = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), x);

const f = s => (...args) => (console.log('function', s, 'length', args.length), args);

compose1(f(1), f(2), f(3))(1, 2, 3);
compose2(f(4), f(5), f(6))(1, 2, 3);
```

The first method may result in a stack overflow if the array of functions is very large because it is pre-composed, whereas the second method is (relatively)<sup>†</sup> stack safe:

```js
const compose1 = (...funcs) => funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), arg => arg);
const compose2 = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), x);

const f = v => v;

try {
  compose1.apply(null, Array.from({ length: 1e5 }, () => f))();
  console.log('1 is safe');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('1 failed');
}

try {
  compose2.apply(null, Array.from({ length: 1e5 }, () => f))();
  console.log('2 is safe');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('2 failed');
}
```

<sup>† The second method will still result in a stack overflow if `...fns` is too large because `arguments` are also allocated on the stack.</sup>

Comment: Brilliant! Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in what structure the reduce-composition actually builds, you can visualize it as follows:

```js
/* original:
const compose = (...funcs) =>
funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), arg => arg);
*/

const compose = (...funcs) =>
  funcs.reduce((a, b) => `((...args) => ${a}(${b}(...args)))`, $_("id"));

const $_ = name =>
  `${name}`;

const id = x => x;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const neg = x => -x;

const computation = compose($_("inc"), $_("sqr"), $_("neg"));

console.log(computation);

/* yields:
((...args) => ((...args) => ((...args) =>
  id(inc(...args))) (sqr(...args))) (neg(...args)))
*/

console.log(eval(computation) (2)); // 5 (= id(inc(sqr(neg(2))))
```

So what is going on here? I replaced the inner function `(...args) => a(b(...args))` with a Template-String and `arg => arg` with the `$_` helper function. Then I wrapped the Template-String in parenthesis, so that the resulting `String` represents an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Last but not least I pass `$_` helper functions with proper names to `compose`.

`$_` is a bit odd but it is really helpful to visualize unapplied/partially applied functions.

You can see from the computational structure that the reduce-composition builds a nested structure of anonymous functions and rest/spread operations are scattered throughout the code.

Visualizing and interpreting partially applied functions is hard. We can simplify it by omitting the inner anonymous function:

```js
const compose = (...funcs) =>
  funcs.reduce($xy("reducer"), $_("id"));

const $_ = name =>
  `${name}`;

const $xy = name => (x, y) =>
  `${name}(${x}, ${y})`;

const id = x => x;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const neg = x => -x;

console.log(
  compose($_("inc"), $_("sqr"), $_("neg"))
  // reducer(reducer(reducer(id, inc), sqr), neg)
);
```

We can further simplify by actually running the composition:

```js
const compose = (...funcs) =>
  funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), $x("id"));

const $x = name => x =>
  `${name}(${x})`;

console.log(
  compose($x("inc"), $x("sqr"), $x("neg")) (2) // id(inc(sqr(neg(2))))
);
```

I believe that the visualization of complex computations like this is a powerful technique to comprehend them correctly and to gain a better understanding of nested/recursive computational structures.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation show and tell? Okay -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const compose = (f = identity, ...fs) => x =>
  f === identity
    ? x
    : compose (...fs) (f (x))
    
const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
  
console .log
  ( compose () (0)                   // 0
  , compose (add1) (0)               // 1
  , compose (add1, add1) (0)         // 2
  , compose (add1, add1, add1) (0)   // 3
  )
```

Or instead of using `compose` in-line ...

```
const ListWithConditionalRendering = compose(
  withLoadingIndicator,
  withDataNull,
  withListEmpty
)(Users);
```

You could make a sort of "forward composition" function where the argument comes first -

```js
const $ = x => k =>
  $ (k (x))
  
const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
  
const double = x =>
  x * 2

$ (0) (add1) (console.log)
// 1

$ (2) (double) (double) (double) (console.log)
// 16

$ (2) (double) (add1) (double) (console.log)
// 10
```

`$` is useful when you can maintain a pattern of -

```
$ (value) (pureFunc) (pureFunc) (pureFunc) (...) (effect)
```

Above, `$` puts a value into a sort of "pipeline", but there's no way to take the value *out*. A small adjustment allows us write very flexible variadic expressions. Below, we use `$` as a way of delimiting the beginning and ending of a pipeline expression.

```js
const $ = x => k =>
  k === $
    ? x
    : $ (k (x))

const double = x =>
  x * 2

const a =
  $ (2) (double) ($)
  
const b =
  $ (3) (double) (double) (double) ($)

console .log (a, b)
// 4 24
```

This variadic interface gives you the ability to write expressions similar to the coveted `|>` operator found in other more function-oriented languages -

```
value
  |> pureFunc
  |> pureFunc
  |> ...
  |> pureFunc

5 |> add1
  |> double
  |> double
  // 24
```

Using `$`, that translates to -

```
$ (value) (pureFunc) (pureFunc) (...) (pureFunc) ($)

$ (5) (add1) (double) (double) ($) // 24
```

The technique also mixes nicely with curried functions -

```js
const $ = x => k =>
  $ (k (x))

const add = x => y =>
  x + y
  
const mult = x => y =>
  x * y
  
$ (1) (add (2)) (mult (3)) (console.log)
// 9
```

Or with a slightly more interesting example -

```js
const $ = x => k =>
  $ (k (x))

const flatMap = f => xs =>
  xs .flatMap (f)
  
const join = y => xs =>
  xs .join (y)
  
const twice = x =>
  [ x, x ]

$ ('mississippi')
  (([...chars]) => chars)
  (flatMap (twice))
  (join (''))
  (console.log)
  // 'mmiissssiissssiippppii'
```